# Get datetime interval in postgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, datetime

I want to get a specific interval datetime from postgresql query. For example, current datetime is '2021-03-21' and then I want to get the specified interval from this date time at day "1" on month "3", and interval to 1 year ago so it got "2020-02-01"

Interval "2020-02-01" to "2021-03-01"

So this is my line of code

```sql
and date_post >= date_trunc('month', '2021-03-01'-interval '1' year)
and date_post < date_trunc('month', '2021-02-01')
```

But I got an error it says:

```
 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type interval: "2021-03-01"
```

Comment: Try: `'2021-03-01'-interval '1 year'` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
and date_post >= date_trunc('month',  CAST('2021-03-01' AS timestamp) - '1 year'::interval)
and date_post < date_trunc('month', CAST('2021-02-01'AS timestamp))
```

You can use date() function to cast from timestamp to date.

Comment: I think the dates are interchange, because you said: Interval "2020-02-01" to "2021-03-01".

Comment: Keep in mind that date_trunc() function truncate to specified precision, in your case month.

Answer (score 0):

Use `date` to introduce a date constant:

```
date_post >= date_trunc('month', date '2021-03-01' - interval '1' year) and
date_post < date_trunc('month', date '2021-02-01')
```

Of course, the `date_trunc()` is not needed for the values you have provided.

If you are constructing the query with the value as a string, you can convert the string using `::date` instead:

```
date_post >= date_trunc('month', '2021-03-01'::date - interval '1' year) and
date_post < date_trunc('month', '2021-02-01'::date)
```

Answer (score 0):

**To get fields of a timestamp, Which is greater than the date in PostgreSQL:**

```
SELECT * from table-name
WHERE your-timestamp > to_date('05 jan 2020', 'DD Mon YYYY');
```

**You can also Subtract hours, years, minutes from the timestamp in PostgreSQL:**

```
SELECT * from table-name
WHERE your-timestamp >now()- interval '1 year 2 day';
```